# Fedora Laptop sometimes does not shut down and overheats instead

Tags: fedora, shutdown

Sometimes (like once a week) when I turn off my laptop, the power is not turned off, while the OS seamingly shuts down. In these instances, the fan turns on maximum power, the battery drains as fast as it can and the laptop overheats very quickly. Apart from that, it doesn't seem to be doing anything. To exit this state I have to long-press the power button in order to turn it off and then I can reboot.

I have a a dualboot with Windows 11 and Fedora 36 on my laptop.
My problem only exists with Fedora not with Windows. It already happened before I updated to Fedora 36.

I already checked journalctl, but systemd does not seem to be doing anything when the problem occurs:

```
May 17 18:05:20 fedora systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices. 
May 17 18:05:20 fedora systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...                   
May 17 18:05:20 fedora systemd-journald[599]: Journal stopped
-- Boot db905880ea424842a81e565789401a84 --
May 17 23:33:07 fedora kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xb0, date = 2022-03-09
May 17 23:33:07 fedora kernel: Linux version 5.17.6-300.fc36.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel01.iad2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc (GCC) 12.0.1 20220413 (Red Hat 12.0.1-0), GNU ld version 2.37-27.fc36) #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 9 15:47:11 UTC 2022
May 17 23:33:07 fedora kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt5)/vmlinuz-5.17.6-300.fc36.x86_64 root=UUID=0b8a49f1-8937-4de8-9501-a43a1a02429d ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1 
May 17 23:33:07 fedora kernel: x86/split lock detection: #AC: crashing the kernel on kernel split_locks and warning on user-space split_locks
May 17 23:33:07 fedora kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers' May 17 23:33:07 fedora kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers' May 17 23:33:07 fedora kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers' May 17 23:33:07 fedora kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x020: 'AVX-512 opmask'
```